# Add increasing number to filename, how not to loop?

Tags: php, numbers, sequence

I'm trying to modify a script that generates random numbers to filenames and instead have a pretty increasing counter of +1 each new file

The original function is very simple it looks like this:

```
$name .= generateRandomString(5);
```

What I've came up with my mediocre skills is:

```
$name .= $count = 1; while ($count <= 10) { echo "$count "; ++$count; }
```

However, what happens when I run the code is that it just keeps on looping. I was looking for a function similar to the: `generateRandomString` but for increasing numbers, is there any?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user current timestamp in place of `$count`, it will always keep increasing.

```
$name .= time()
```